# Combining association p-values from different H0 families

Tags: p-value, combining-p-values

I have a pipeline that finds pairwise associations between three objects that are in a relationship as follows:

```
    B
  /   \
 A --- C
```

What I get from this pipeline is a p-value for each pairwise association: either AB, AC or BC. I need a way to combine them to get a plausible p-value-based metric to characterize the whole ABC interaction (let's suppose that if AB, AC and BC occur simultaneously, then ABC also occurs). The only problem I have is that p-values come from statistical tests that rely on different hypotheses, which renders them unusable in Fisher's method or its modifications.

Is there a way to combine p-values in a way that can describe the significance of finding ABC from significances of finding AB, BC and AC?

Comment: As an aside the main methods for combining p-values do not rely on testing the same hypothesis, they just test against the null that the p-values are drawn from a uniform on 0,1. Having said that it does not solve your problem of course.